# Tannakian fundamental group of automorphic representations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms

Let $\mathcal{C}_{\mathrm{aut}}(G, F)$ be the category of automorphic representations of a connected reductive group $G$ over a number field $F$.

If this is a Tannakian category, it has an associated Tannakian fundamental group $G^{\mathrm{aut}}_F$. What is it and how is it related to $G$ itself (for example, for $G = \operatorname{GL}_n$)? In other words, what does Tannakian duality recover in this case?

EDIT: In light of Bugs Bunny's answer below, if we consider the group of endomorphisms of the forgetful functor from $\mathcal{C}_{\mathrm{aut}}(G, F)$ (with completed tensor product) to the category of Hilbert spaces, how is the group related to $G$?

Comment: *Is* it a Tannakian category?

Comment: I'm a layman here, but I expect a link with the absolute Galois group of $F$ in the case $G=GL_{n}$.

Comment: Actually, the category you consider may consist of L-rigs (a quick search will give you the questions I asked about them) and morphisms thereof.

Comment: Downvoted. The question is misguided since there is no natural abelian (let alone Tannakian) category structure on $\mathcal{C}_{\mathrm{aut}}(G, F)$ -- by definition automorphic reps are irreducible, so how will you define direct sum?

Comment: Not directly, but in his 1988 Ann Arbor talk Clozel "describes certain categories of automorphic representations which should be subject to a tannakian formalism".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a tannakian category. The issue is the tensor product. Let $V$ and $W$ be automorphic representations. The algebraic tensor product $V\otimes W$ is no longer automorphic. You need some kind of completion $V\widehat{\otimes}W$ but, according to David Loeffler, the completion is too big to be automorphic.

Comment: Is there a version of Tannakian theory with the required completed tensor product that can be applied to get a Tannakian group for which the question is meaningful?

Comment: The more general related question I have is "to what extent can we restrict the category of representations in classical Tannaka duality to still get full reconstruction? If we take only a subcategory of representations of a group, which aspects of the group can we still recover from the endomorphisms of the restricted fiber functor?" Has this question been investigated for some specific situations?

Comment: Sure, why not? Tannakian formalism is quite universal but I do not know where it is written over Hilbert spaces. Your monoidal forgetful functor goes to the category of Hilbert spaces. You can do coend on it and will probably get $L^2(G)$ back...

Comment: Just to know, assuming the Rankin-Selberg convolution of two automorphic representations is also automorphic, could it play the role of the tensor product?

Comment: This is nonsense I'm afraid. There is no way to "complete" $V \otimes W$ to make it into an automorphic representation of $G$ -- it's just far too big. You can make it into an automorphic representation of $G \times G$, rather boringly; but the OP wanted a category structure on the automorphic reps of a fixed group $G$ and there's simply no sensible way of doing this.

Comment: It would be nice if the OP could tell us if they really meant $G=GL_{n}$ for fixed $n$ for the whole category or for a given object thereof.

Comment: @David Loeffler I believe you. I will change the answer slightly,

Comment: It turns out that it is possible to define a better behaved monodical structure, at least in the case of $\mathrm{GL}_2$. I have a paper about this: [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.03313). (I apologize if it is inappropriate to point at my own paper.)

Comment: @David Loeffler Now I have doubts:-)) Why cannot you just generate a tensor category by automorphic representations? The tensor product will be just the completed tensor product of Hilbert spaces.

Comment: @GalDor, Thanks a lot for your fascinating thesis! I have been looking for something like your construction. I am wondering about the reasons it is restricted to $GL_2$.

Comment: @BugsBunny, Thank you for your suggestions! I'll think about Tannakian formalism in the generated category, using Gal Dor's paper as a guide as well.